# How to replace the default failed img in Android's WebView

Tags: android, image, webview, default

If an `img` tag load failed in webview,it shows a `"?"` in blue background color.
How can I replace the default `img` or hide it in **Android Code**?
I want to hide it in Android Code, because in javascript, I can use `onerror` or `onload` events to solve the problem, but in that way, I have to bind events to all `img` tag, so I want to find a way in Android Code. I guess `webview` may have some setting or event to do it, but I don't know.

Comment: cant you use JS for the same ?

Comment: See this example: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/binding-javascript-and-android-code-example/ once.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code it may guide you to a solution:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @TargetApi(11)
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
       return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
    }
};
```